# Java rounding by specific step

Tags: java, rounding

Frequently we need to round a number like an amount for minimum currency granularity like 0.05.

I faced an overflow problem in Java, and have seemingly solved it...would like you to review if it's a correct solution...there are other solutions present on this forum as well...

```
public static float round(float input, float step) {

float a = Math.round(input / step) * step;

//Can't return "a" directly because of overflow problem in some cases
int b = Math.round(a * 100);

return (float) (float)b / 100f; }
```

But this will only work for 2 decimal place step (like 0.05) as I am hard coding 100 here...

Comment: What "overflow problem"?

Comment: @Sumedh, I wouldn't use `float` unless I really had to,  It has up to one billion times the rounding error of `double`. Using `double` is a better choice 99% of the time.

Comment: @Peter: anywhere the word "currency" appears, both float and double are a bad choice

Comment: Overflow problem - If you pass say 1.28 and 0.05 to the first line above, you get 1.3000001 not 1.3...

Answer (score 15):

This will work for any step size:

```
public static float round(float input, float step) 
{
  return ((Math.round(input / step)) * step);
}
```

Comment: somebody loves brackets )

Answer (score 5):

If you work with hundreds of decimals, `float` is not the type you need. May I redirect you to [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?